# dim() called on undefined Tensor (dim at ../c10/core/UndefinedTensorImpl.cpp:24) in Libtorch C++

Tags: c++, libtorch

I get the error(shown below) when executing an image.
I used Python to trace the Yolo model and the traced file in the C++ environment gives the error for only one image.
I guess the error might be due to the image not having any object detection.

```
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
  what():  dim() called on undefined Tensor (dim at ../c10/core/UndefinedTensorImpl.cpp:24)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0x6a (0x7f8e4ec3baaa in libtorch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::UndefinedTensorImpl::dim() const + 0x258 (0x7f8e4ec33258 in libtorch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: at::native::size(at::Tensor const&, long) + 0x15 (0x7f8e408ca4a5 in libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x3464a (0x556c2485164a in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x2fb1b (0x556c2484cb1b in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #5: long c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxed<long, at::Tensor const&, long>(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, long) const + 0x8f (0x556c24847e41 in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #6: <unknown function> + 0x244f3 (0x556c248414f3 in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #7: at::Tensor::size(long) const + 0x83 (0x556c24837c13 in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #8: <unknown function> + 0xeef1 (0x556c2482bef1 in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)
frame #9: __libc_start_main + 0xe7 (0x7f8e01096b97 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #10: <unknown function> + 0xa65a (0x556c2482765a in ./Torchimport_YOLO3)**
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but no one here will be able to provide any help knowing only the error message. Please provide a minimal code example and a bit of context : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also please clarify your your question, because I really do not understand "the image not having any object detection" :)

Comment: How are you using this in the C++ side? please provide some snippets so we can help you